# Why is text content making a column wider?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am setting up a video player in CSS Grid and for the life of me can't figure out why the width of the right most grid column (one with three multi-colored rows) increases when I add text content.

I have tried setting the `overflow` property to `hidden` but the width still changes.

If I remove the following code from the html markup, the column goes back to the desired width:

```
<div id="title">This Text</div>
<div id="location">is making this 3 row div</div>
<div id="date">wider for some reason</div>
```

I want to add text to the column without the width changing. Probably an easy fix. Thanks for any help!

https://codepen.io/Wcomp/pen/LKMrRK?editors=1100

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

*:focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.middle {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'item1 item1 item1 item1 item2';
  grid-column-gap: 3vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 23.3333666667%;
  height: 53.3332667%;
  border-left: 3vh solid transparent;
  border-right: 3vh solid transparent;
}

.vid_player {
  display: grid;
  background-color: green;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 3vh;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-area: item1;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  grid-area: item2;
}

#one {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#two {
  background-color: red;
}

#three {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#title {
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#location {
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#date {
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">

  <div class="vid_player">

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>



  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <div id="one">

      <div id="title">This Text</div>
      <div id="location">is making this 3 row div</div>
      <div id="date">wider for some reason</div>

    </div>

    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it give the expected result if you add `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;` to your `.middle` class?

Answer (score 0):

By making all of the columns `1fr` wide, you are telling the browser to make all of them take up the same amount of **remaining** space left on the page. That is, the space left after your content-filled columns have taken up what they need.

If you want the columns to take up the same amount of space no matter what try giving them widths in [`vw` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units) to make their width a fraction of the screen, or percents to make their width a fraction of their parent's width.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you define your primary grid container:

```
.middle {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'item1 item1 item1 item1 item2';
}
```

You've created a grid with five columns.

However, you haven't specified a width for these columns. In other words, you haven't defined any values for `grid-template-columns`.

As a result, each column defaults to the width of its content.

Because the column in question has text content, unlike the other columns, it is wider.

Set a rule for equal widths. Add this to your code:

```
.middle {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'item1 item1 item1 item1 item2';
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); /* new */
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XLoxRy?editors=1100)

```css
.middle {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "item1 item1 item1 item1 item2";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); /* new */
  grid-column-gap: 3vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 23.3333666667%;
  height: 53.3332667%;
  border-left: 3vh solid transparent;
  border-right: 3vh solid transparent;
}

.vid_player {
  display: grid;
  background-color: green;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 3vh;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-area: item1;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  grid-area: item2;
}

#one {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#two {
  background-color: red;
}

#three {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#title {
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#location {
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#date {
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

*:focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <div class="vid_player">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="one">
      <div id="title">This Text</div>
      <div id="location">is making this 3 row div</div>
      <div id="date">wider for some reason</div>
    </div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```